# How to print something between two string in a line

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I'm new to linux and trying to print something between strings in a logline.

Below is the input file:

```
  2018-04-15 00:01:22  https://abc123456.net;~galv=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abc.es%sadn.html? Mozilla/5.0
```

And I'm trying to print the URL between galv= and ? as output:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abc.es%sadn.html
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `grep -oP 'galv=\K[^?]+'` should work

Comment: Thanks it works!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score -1):

If you use:

```
echo "2018-04-15 00:01:22 https://abc123456.net;~galv=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abc.es%sadn.html? Mozilla/5.0" | awk -v FS="(~galv=|?)" '{print $2}'
```

it will give you correct output. For further use you can follow the below syntax

```
awk -v FS="(FROM_KEYWORD|TO_KEYWORD)" '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score -1):

try this -

`$cat inputfile
2018-04-15 00:01:22  https://abc123456.net;~galv=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abc.es%sadn.html? Mozilla/5.0`

`$awk -F'[=,?]' '{ print $2}' inputfile
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abc.es%sadn.html`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this awk (all awk I think)

```
awk '{gsub(/.*galv=|\?.*/,"")}1' infile
```